# Che cosa significa "una scarpa sul naso"?

Tags: phrases

Che cosa significa "una scarpa sul naso" in questo contesto?

```
Un uomo si scuote, fa un salto mortale,
il padre lo bacia, lo bacia suo padre.
Gli dà un altro bacio e una scarpa sul naso
e poi un altro bacio,
poi ci ripensa e gli dà un'altra scarpa sul naso
e poi se ne va.
```

Comment: Non mettere “tag” a casaccio, per piacere.

Comment: Penso che quello che ho postato sia sufficiente, se conosci la risposta rispondi, se non lo sai, passa a un'altra domanda.

Comment: Leo, ti consiglio di leggere le pagine di [“Help”](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help) di questo sito, e in particolare [su come porre le domande](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

“Gli dà ... una scarpa sul naso” significa semplicemente che gli colpisce il naso con una scarpa, non è una frase idiomatica o un modo di dire.

Ancora una volta: per piacere, quando fai una domanda specifica il contesto. Di chi è la canzone, di quando? Io l'ho trovata, ma se vuoi che qualcuno ti risponda sarebbe più cortese non costringerlo a fare delle ricerche su cose che magari tu già sai.

Nello specifico, si tratta di *È arrivata la bufera*, una canzone umoristica del 1939 (ma pubblicata molti anni dopo) scritta e cantata da Renato Rascel. Da una parte è importante notare che tutto il testo è un po' surreale (“Nel suo morbido lettino, / dorme placido Pierino / e suo zio ch’è di Voghera / sta danzando l’habanera”). Dall'altra c'è un senso di angoscia velata, di attesa, perché era veramente in arrivo la “bufera” della Seconda guerra mondiale, il che forse contribuisce a spiegare anche l'immagine violenta del padre che bacia e percuote il figlio.

Comment: Non credo che ti colpisca il naso con una scarpa. Ho pensato che potesse essere "uno schiaffo nel naso"

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo: Che cosa intendi con “uno schiaffo nel naso”? Non è un'espressione usuale in italiano.

Comment: Mamma mia!! Dev'essere roba italiana, sbatterti il ​​naso con le scarpe

Comment: Leo, esatto, proprio come ballare l'habanera.